# In Costume Quest, does making monsters flee mean lower rewards?

Tags: costume-quest

There are some Battle Stamps and costume abilities that can terrify and cause enemies to take flight, effectively removing them from the battle immediately.

However, does this mean that you get less candy and XP at the end of the battle?

Comment: Gah, I don't remember! I think I avoided those in favor of just killing them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From what I remember, the candies and XP are award at the end of the battle if you have defeated your opponent, whatever the technique you use!

So you don't have a lower reward if you're making monsters flee during the battle. You'll get the same thing at the end provided you win.